# No reconoce entity framework en Visual Studio 2013!

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

al momento de crear la conexión a la base de datos e instanciar en el código, no me reconoce la entidad que se creo, ¿A que se deberá ese problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Donde creas la variable `Model`? , cual es su tipo? es imposible ayudarte, falta muchísima información en tu pregunta para replicar tu problema..

Comment: Hola. Has incluido en esa clase el `using` correspondiente al espacio de nombres donde se encuentra ubicado Model?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal lo que pasa es que, el model debe ser detectado automaticamente, antes de mencionar el entity que se creo para la conexión con la BD. Pero ahi, lo pide realizar como clase, es precisamente lo que no entiendo, porque algunos hacen la referencia y les aparece inmediatamente.

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra donde te refieres tu?

Comment: Si vas al archivo DB.cs, qué `namespace` tiene? Si difiere del espacio de nombres de tu archivo `MenuYLista.xaml.cs`, debes incluirlo